# Unable to display image in form view

Tags: acumatica

I have unbound field and assigning file id to it, I even tried assign URL also but that is not working, please have a look at below design and code, please let me know where am doing a mistake.

```
<px:PXFormView runat="server" ID="frmImage2" DataSourceID="ds" DataMember="IconImage" SkinID="Preview">
                <Template>
                    <px:PXLayoutRule ID="PXLayoutRule18" runat="server" StartColumn="true" />
                    <px:PXImageUploader runat="server" DataField="UsrKWJMThumbnailURL" AllowUpload="false" DataMember="IconImage" SuppressLabel="True" ID="imgViewImage12" Height="150px" Width="150px" />
                </Template>
    </px:PXFormView>

     public PXSelect<AMProdItem> IconImage;

        public virtual void iconImage()
        {
            foreach (AMProdItem item in Base.ProdItemRecords.Select())
            {
                AMProdItemExt extItems = item.GetExtension<AMProdItemExt>();

                if (extItems != null)
                {
                    if (extItems.UsrKWJMSerialNbr != null)
                    {
                        InfoSmartSearch.InfoINItemLotSerialImage infoItemLotSerialImg = PXSelectReadonly<InfoSmartSearch.InfoINItemLotSerialImage, Where<InfoSmartSearch.InfoINItemLotSerialImage.lotSerialNbr, Equal<Required<InfoSmartSearch.InfoINItemLotSerialImage.lotSerialNbr>>>>.Select(Base, extItems.UsrKWJMSerialNbr);

                        if (infoItemLotSerialImg != null)
                        {
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(infoItemLotSerialImg.UsrIconImageUrl))
                            {
                                NoteDoc noteDoc = PXSelectReadonly<NoteDoc, Where<NoteDoc.noteID, Equal<Required<NoteDoc.noteID>>>>.Select(Base, infoItemLotSerialImg.NoteID);

                                if (noteDoc != null)
                                {
                                    UploadFile uploadFile = PXSelectReadonly<UploadFile, Where<UploadFile.fileID, Equal<Required<UploadFile.fileID>>>>.Select(Base, noteDoc.FileID);

                                    if (uploadFile != null)
                                    {
                                        extItems.UsrKWJMThumbnailURL =
                                           ControlHelper.GetAttachedFileUrl(null, uploadFile.FileID.ToString());
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        InventoryItem invItems = PXSelectReadonly<InventoryItem, Where<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<Required<InventoryItem.inventoryID>>>>.Select(Base, item.InventoryID);

                        if (invItems != null)
                        {
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(invItems.ImageUrl))
                            {
                                NoteDoc noteDoc = PXSelectReadonly<NoteDoc, Where<NoteDoc.noteID, Equal<Required<NoteDoc.noteID>>>>.Select(Base, invItems.NoteID);

                                if (noteDoc != null)
                                {
                                    UploadFile uploadFile = PXSelectReadonly<UploadFile, Where<UploadFile.fileID, Equal<Required<UploadFile.fileID>>>>.Select(Base, noteDoc.FileID);

                                    if (uploadFile != null)
                                    {
                                        extItems.UsrKWJMThumbnailURL =
                                          ControlHelper.GetAttachedFileUrl(null, uploadFile.FileID.ToString());
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: it would be best to include the code example in your question and not an external link. More so if the external link is eventually removed/broken.

Comment: Thanks Brendan for your view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use PXImageView control instead of PXImageUploader.

```
<px:PXImageView runat="server" ID="edImage" DataField="UsrKWJMThumbnailURL" />
```

Also test with an absolute URL first like this one:
https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png

I tested this method and can vouch for it:
[image]

Here's the complete code of my test project:

```
using System;
using PX.Data;

namespace PXImageTest
{
  public class TestImage : PXGraph<TestImage>
  {
    public PXFilter<MasterTable> MasterView;

    public void MasterTable_ImageUrl_FieldSelecting(PXCache sender, PXFieldSelectingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.ReturnValue = "https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png";
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class MasterTable : IBqlTable
    {
      public abstract class imageUrl : IBqlField { }

      [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Image")]
      [PXDBString(255, IsUnicode = true)]  
      public virtual String ImageUrl { get; set; }
    }
  }
}
```

ASPX:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/FormView.master" AutoEventWireup="true" ValidateRequest="false" CodeFile="ZZ999999.aspx.cs" Inherits="Page_ZZ999999" Title="Untitled Page" %>
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/MasterPages/FormView.master" %>

<asp:Content ID="cont1" ContentPlaceHolderID="phDS" Runat="Server">
    <px:PXDataSource ID="ds" runat="server" Visible="True" Width="100%"
        TypeName="PXImageTest.TestImage"
        PrimaryView="MasterView">
        <CallbackCommands>
        </CallbackCommands>
    </px:PXDataSource>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="cont2" ContentPlaceHolderID="phF" Runat="Server">
    <px:PXFormView ID="form" runat="server" DataSourceID="ds" DataMember="MasterView" Width="100%" AllowAutoHide="false">
        <Template>
            <px:PXLayoutRule runat="server" StartRow="True" ID="PXLayoutRule1" />
            <px:PXImageView runat="server" DataField="ImageUrl" ID="edImage" Style='left:9px;top:9px;Position:absolute;' />
        </Template>
        <AutoSize Container="Window" Enabled="True" MinHeight="200" ></AutoSize>
    </px:PXFormView>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Thanks HB_ACUMATICA, how can we hide "ATTACH FILE" and "NOTES" properties which are coming on top of image control.

Comment: i have added same in two places 1) in form header section which is showing properties and 2) in tab section where it is not showing properties.

Comment: Can you add images to your question to illustrate what you are asking about?

Comment: Please ignore it, Thank you very much :)